# Hard coded data in global store does not show in extjs grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6-classic

I've got an extjs global store have I have hard coded with fields and data:

```
Ext.define('Registration.store.SavedSessions',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    storeId: 'savedsessions',

    fields:[
    "id",
    "title",
    "dateStart"
    ],

    data: [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: 'test',
            dateStart: new Date()
        }
    ]

});
```

The global store is registered via the Application.js file:

```
Ext.define('Registration.Application', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Application',

    name: 'Registration',

    stores: [
        'SavedSessions'
    ],
    ...
```

I also have a grid that I'm trying to load the store into:

```
Ext.define("Registration.view.cart.savedsessions.SavedSessions",{
    extend: "Ext.grid.Panel",

    xtype: 'savedsessions',

    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('savedsessions'),

    columns:[
        {
            text: 'Date',
            dataIndex: 'dateStart'
        },
        {
            text: 'Title',
            dataIndex: 'title',
            flex: 1
        }
    ]
});
```

Looking at the docs this all looks correct. The problem I'm running into is that the store doesn't load.

When I open up the javascript console and count the number of records in the grid's store I get 0:

[image: store from the grid]

I'm not sure how this can happen at all considering the data is hard coded into the store.

Also, when I grab the store directly from the javascript console I can get the hard coded data:

[image: store grabbed directly in js console]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use the `StoreManager` to get the `store`? Just use the [`storeId`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-cfg-store):

```
store: 'savedsessions',
```

Comment: Thanks. That definitely fixed it. I was rushing through and went by the [first example they show in the docs for the grid](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel). I've not used a lot of global stores yet (I mostly use stores in my viewmodel) and for some reason I thought that the storeId is what you needed to look the store up with the storemanager. Thanks for pointing out that it's not needed. That said, do you know why it would get the store but not the hard coded data when pulled via the store manager?

Comment: It could have several reasons. It could be the order of loading the views and the stores, the way how the framework is ladoing and instantiating the views and other objects. The framework is first loading all your class declarations, then after that it instantiate those classes only if needed. So your view declaration is already loaded, before the store is instantiated is guess.

Keep in mind that you never use objects on your view declaration. Don't use managers (I never use them at all), don't use `new` or whatever. https://sencha.guru/2015/07/29/instances-on-prototype-are-bad/

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for that additional clarification and, as always, for your help.